# WinCE 6.0 device cannot access network shares

Tags: windows, networking, shared-folders, embedded

We are using some sort of embedded device which runs on WinCE 6.0. It's connected to our network via domain with DHCP enabled.

Now, to access a shared folder of another system running WinCE or Windows 7 we generally use `\\\COMPUTER-NAME\SHARE-NAME` from the run window.

The issue is, sometimes we are not able to access these shares from a WinCE device. I tried `ipconfig release`, `renew`, `flushdns`, also tried assigning static IP. In all the cases it fails. I even remember once I connected the device to one of the Windows 7 PCs directly using a crossover cable, but I had no luck.

Can anyone can point out any issues?

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: Standard windows error dialog which says "Can not find (compauter name / path). Make sure you typed the name correct....."